# Why can't my javascript redirect the following code, I've tried multiple solution that i found in StackOverFlow

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried multiple of things making the code to redirect, my teacher told me that I need to use method POST, while the following code is the working one which the method get, if I change the method to POST it cannot redirect. I tried using the location.href inside my code, it doesn't seem to work at all. I even tried putting the return false in my javascript. May I know how can I fix these issues?

The following are my code for my form

```
<form action="/Membership/member-profilepage/member_home.html">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-1">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="rmbpw" name="rmbpw" value="rmbpw">
                        <label for="rmbpw" id="rmbpw" name="rmbpw">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RememberMe</label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="login()">
                    </div>
                    <script src="login.js"></script>
                </div>
            </form>
```

This will be the code for my javascript

```
function login(){
    alert("Login Successfully!");
    
}
```

Comment: If I use the form action to do the redirection without the method POST it works perfectly, but when I use the POST method, it doesn't redirect anymore

Comment: There's nothing in the JS code affecting to the redirection nevetheless the value of `method` attribute is.

Comment: Can you show the code that is doing the redirecting?

Comment: You are calling login function on click which will trigger alert method , unless you click 'ok' you cant move forward. Replace ```alert``` with ```console.log('Login successful')```  to debug.

Comment: The code i posted, is the code that actually working for the redirection.

Comment: When i changed it to method="post", then it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I click ok, it moved to the next page... but then the page got error. Like it can't find the path!? but I make sure I copy the right path tho..

Comment: This page isn’t working If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 405 , i get this error message

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code in the post. It's a server-side issue, your server doesn't allow POST method.

Comment: oh i see... cause i'm using the vscode live server @_@ idk about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, Guys, I figure out an answer after doing a couple more research and trying a few more things. I cannot use input type="submit". Hence, I need to use input type="button" to do the redirection.